# Why is Docker Tomcat failing to start?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Tomcat image from a Dockerfile. This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM dockerfile/java

RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install tomcat7

EXPOSE 8086

CMD sudo service tomcat7 start && tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out.
```

but when I build an image from this and run the image with

```
$ docker run tomcat7-test
```

it gives the following:

> Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7 …fail!

I don’t know what is causing the problem. How can I check the logs of this Docker Tomcat? Can anybody tell me what commands I should use in the Dockerfile to run Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [official Tomcat image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) you can use. There are links to the Dockerfiles there to checkout and install Tomcat.

If you want to inspect what is going on when you build your dockerfile, just perform the same steps (apt-getting tomcat7 and starting the service) manually after starting an interactive shell inside the dockerfile/java container with this command:

```
docker -it dockerfile/java bash
```

There you will be able to check the logs and see what could be going on.

Answer (score 0):

I did install tomcat server in the docker container instead of using the official Tomcat image.

When I start the server I get the fail response but was `curl` the `tomcat server` index page.

Also instead of exiting the container, if you detach from it back to your terminal by typing:

> ctrl-p then ctrl-q ([source](http://blog.denevell.org/category_docker.html))

You can access your webapps from browser using the below URL:

> http://<< boot2docker_ip >>:8080

Answer (score 0):

Try running the image with following command

```
docker run -dt --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -p 8082:8080 tomcat7-test
```